# Import many variables from Tkinter GUI into another script without realaunching GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI with many variables that are obtained from a user's input. I then have a separate script that calls each of these variables for use in downstream calculations. The issue is that when I call a variable from the second script, it relaunches the GUI each time. Is there a way around this, so that the variables are available without relaunching the GUI again?

`GUI.py:`

```
root = Tk()
choice1 =  IntVar()
choice2 = IntVar()
choice3 =  StringVar()
root.mainloop()
```

*I have simplified the GUI script above, but essentially the user inputs their values into a Tkinter Entry box, and the input is assigned to the variable when a "submit" button is clicked.

`retrieve.py:`

```
from GUI import choice1
from GUI import choice2
from GUI import choice3
```

I have also tried rewriting `retrieve.py`, but the same results were produced:

```
from GUI import *
```

Comment: you should save data in file and other script should read data from file - it can't get value from variable `choice1` because `import` creates new variables without access to variables in running `GUI`

Comment: how do you run `retrieve.py`? If you run it manually in other console then you have to use file for data. And if you run it in `GUI.py` using `os.system` then maybe you shoould rather `import retrieve` into `GUI.py` and run function directly `retrieve.somefunction(choice1.get(), choice2.get(), choice3.get())`. Eventually your `retrieve.py` should use `sys.argv` get values from command line line `python retrieve.py value1 value2 value3` and then GUI.py can run it as `os.system(f"python python retrieve.py {choice1.get()} {choice2.get()} {choice3.get()}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `retrieve.py` as separate script then all your idea is wrong.

Every program runs in separated process with separated memory (for security: (1) so one program can't get passwords to your bank account from other program, (2) when one program crashs then other programs still can work).

When `retrieve.py` imports other module then it runs all code for the beginning and it creates new variables in own memory and it doesn't give access to variables created when you run `GUI.py`.

`GUI.py` should write data in file, and `retrieve.py` should read data from this file.

More complex method is to use `socket`, `queue` or `shmem` (shared memory) to communicate between processes.

---

**GUI.py**

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import json

# --- functions ---

def save():
    data = [choice1.get(), choice2.get(), choice3.get()]
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(data, fh)
        label['text'] = 'saved'
    
# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

choice1 = tk.IntVar(root)
choice2 = tk.IntVar(root)
choice3 = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=choice1)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=choice2)
entry2.pack()

entry3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=choice3)
entry3.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=save)
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**retrieve.py**

```
import json

# --- functions ---

def load():
    with open('data.json') as fh:
        data = json.load(fh)
        return data
    
# --- main ---

data = load()

if data:

    choice1, choice2, choice3 = data
    
    print('choice1:', choice1)
    print('choice2:', choice2)
    print('choice3:', choice3)

else:

    print('wrong file')
```

Comment: By "write data in file", do you mean write the data to a .txt file and have `retrieve.py` read the .txt file?

Comment: I means write in any type of file - you can use .txt but sometimes simpler is to write as .json or use module `pickle`, `csv` or `pandas`. But you can even use module `SQLite` to write in database.

Comment: I added example code which use file to send data.

Comment: In case I have a large database, is writing the data inside a JSON file still a good idea or there's a better / quicker method?